# Editing description/screenshots on a published app

Tags: android, google-play

I have published a free app on the android market. I want to edit the description and add a couple of screen shots.

While the  "Upload Aplication" screen on http://market.android.com/publish lets me make these changes & saves them too, they don't show up in the description of the app when I go the android market. Do I have to unpublish & republish the app (in which case I might run into version issues)?

Or else, how do I make these changes to description appear on the android market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it doesn't show up instantly but after some time (in my case over 20 minutes!)
Just wanted to share in case someone has the same problem.